# How do I get the localhost name in PowerShell?

Tags: .net, powershell

How do I get the localhost (machine) name in PowerShell? I am using PowerShell 1.0.

Answer (score 303, accepted):

You can just use the .NET Framework method:

`[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostName()`

also

`$env:COMPUTERNAME`

Comment: Note: if your DNS name is longer than 15 characters, `[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostName()` (doesn't truncate) is better than `$env:COMPUTERNAME` (truncates)

Comment: On Windows 10 Enterprise, env:COMPUTERNAME produced the following error: env:COMPUTERNAME : The term 'env:COMPUTERNAME' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At line:1 char:1
+ env:COMPUTERNAME
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (env:COMPUTERNAME:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: @mathisfun `$env:COMPUTERNAME` works fine on Windows 10 (please note dollar sign at the beginning)

Comment: `$env:COMPUTERNAME` won't work on Linux and macOS. However, `[Environment]::MachineName` does.

Answer (score 71):

Don't forget that all your old console utilities work just fine in PowerShell:

```
PS> hostname
KEITH1
```

Comment: This is a good answer, however, if you want to save the value in a variable then use the accepted answer.

Comment: You can store the value as follows `$name = $(hostname)`

Answer (score 40):

Long form:

```
get-content env:computername
```

Short form:

```
gc env:computername
```

Comment: supershort: $env:COMPUTERNAME

Comment: This will work fine, until you have a server with a name longer than 15 characters.

Comment: @GaryPendlebury what will happen then?

Comment: @Sajuuk `computername` is the NetBIOS name, which is limited to 15 characters.

Answer (score 18):

All above questions are correct but if you want the hostname and domain name try this:

```
 [System.Net.DNS]::GetHostByName('').HostName
```

Answer (score 8):

A slight tweak on @CPU-100's answer, for the local FQDN:

`[System.Net.DNS]::GetHostByName($Null).HostName`

Answer (score 7):

In PowerShell Core v6 (works on macOS, Linux and Windows):

```
[Environment]::MachineName
```

Answer (score 5):

`hostname` also works just fine in Powershell

Comment: I can confirm that this works on PowerShell Core 7.3.1 on macOS as well as PowerShell on Windows 10.

Answer (score 3):

An analogue of the bat file code in Powershell

Cmd

```
wmic path Win32_ComputerSystem get Name
```

Powershell

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name
```

and ...

```
hostname.exe
```

Answer (score 3):

Not specifically for Powershell version 1.0 and more of an overview of different possible ways to get information via Powershell:

- Native CmdLet (usually the best, but sadly really slow to get the Computername):
  `(Get-ComputerInfo).CsDNSHostName`
  Returns the "Name of local computer according to the domain name server" ([Info about `Get-ComputerInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-computerinfo), [Info about its return value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.computerinfo))
- Classical CommandLine executable:
  `hostname.exe`
  Returns the "host name portion of the full computer name of the computer" ([Info about `hostname.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/hostname)
- Environment Variable:
  `$env:COMPUTERNAME`
- Registry:
  `(Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ActiveComputerName).ComputerName`
- Static .Net Property:
  `[Environment]::MachineName`
  Returns "the NetBIOS name of this local computer." ([Info about the `System.Environment` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment#properties))
- Static .Net Method:
  `[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry("").HostName`
  Returns the DNS Hostname (fqdn) of the system ([Info about the `System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.dns.gethostentry))
- Property of COM-Object (Computername via deprecated Scripting-Api):
  `(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).ComputerName`
  Returns "the name of the computer system." ([Info about the WshNetwork Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6wt333f.aspx), [Info about the Windows Script Host Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f51wc7hz.aspx))
- Property of WMI-Object:
  `(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem).Name`
  ([Info about Win32_ComputerSystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-computersystem))
- P/Invoke a native API function:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
    public enum COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT{
        ComputerNameNetBIOS,
        ComputerNameDnsHostname,
        ComputerNameDnsDomain,
        ComputerNameDnsFullyQualified,
        ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS,
        ComputerNamePhysicalDnsHostname,
        ComputerNamePhysicalDnsDomain,
        ComputerNamePhysicalDnsFullyQualified,
        ComputerNameMax,
    }
    public static class Kernel32{
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern bool GetComputerNameEx(COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT NameType, System.Text.StringBuilder lpBuffer, ref uint lpnSize);
    }
'@
$len = 0
[Kernel32]::GetComputerNameEx([COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT]::ComputerNameDnsFullyQualified, $null, [ref]$len); #get required size
$sb = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new([int]$len) #create StringBuilder with required capacity (ensure int constructor is used, otherwise powershell chooses string constructor for uint value...)
$len = $sb.Capacity #get actual capacity of StringBuilder (important, as maybe StringBuilder was constructed differently than expected)
[Kernel32]::GetComputerNameEx([COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT]::ComputerNameDnsFullyQualified, $sb, [ref]$len);
$sb.ToString()
```

Returns "The fully qualified DNS name that uniquely identifies the local computer. This name is a combination of the DNS host name and the DNS domain name, using the form HostName.DomainName. If the local computer is a node in a cluster, lpBuffer receives the fully qualified DNS name of the cluster virtual server."
([Info about the `GetComputerNameEx` API function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getcomputernameexw), [Info about the `COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT` enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/ne-sysinfoapi-computer_name_format), [used c# signature of `COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT` (unofficial)](https://github.com/dahall/Vanara/blob/073d59b34c3e0cb8e6c657eaccf8eee7742d859c/PInvoke/Kernel32/SysInfoApi.cs#L24--L70), [used c# signature of `GetComputerNameEx` (unofficial)](https://github.com/dahall/Vanara/blob/073d59b34c3e0cb8e6c657eaccf8eee7742d859c/PInvoke/Kernel32/SysInfoApi.cs#L921--L924), [short blogpost about P/Invoke in powershell](https://www.leeholmes.com/powershell-pinvoke-walkthrough/))
Note: Use P/Invoke with caution. Sufficiently incorrect usage can actually make powershell crash. The `Add-Type` call is somewhat slow (but only needs to be called once in the script).

Answer (score 2):

The most descriptive way for me is:

```
[System.Net.DNS]::GetHostByName($env:COMPUTERNAME).HostName
```

Answer (score 1):

> You can store the value as follows `$name = $(hostname)`

I want to add that simply executing `$name = hostname` will also save the localhost name of the PC into a variable.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30764121)