# Is there anyway to get the hostname in the script automatically?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, uninstallation

I am trying to uninstall an application from the 50 windows machine and was thinking to run the uninstallation script through group policy but need help where my script can get the hostname automatically when it runs on the machine.

Comment: `echo %USERDOMAIN%`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the localhost name in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169891/how-do-i-get-the-localhost-name-in-powershell)

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell:

```
$env:COMPUTERNAME
```

or

```
[Environment]::MachineName
```

or

```
hostname
```

or

```
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostName()
```

or

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

or

```
Get-CimInstance CIM_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

CMD:

```
hostname
```

or

```
echo %COMPUTERNAME%
```

Comment: thanks for the useful _and_ amusing answer! [*grin*]